# How do insert multiple entities and return them in TypeORM

Tags: node.js, express, graphql, typeorm

Let's say i have a Vote entity. I want to insert an array with 5 votes simultaneously and return them. I have tried : await Vote.save(votes) but that doesnt work and it doesnt return them either. Any ideas?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Firstly you need to prepare entities instances *(it's not just an object which you must probably have made in some place)*:

```
const votesEntities = Vote.create(votes);
```

And then you could save these entities:

```
await Vote.save(votesEntities);
```

But I would advise to use an `insert` instead of `save` *(because `save` forms a separate query to DB for each entity)* and return previously prepared entities. How it might look in the end:

```
async insertVotes(votes) {
  const votesEntities = Vote.create(votes);
  await Vote.insert(votesEntities);
  return votesEntities;
}
```